# Slicknav Javascript will not execute on page in a subdirectory

Tags: subdirectory, slicknav

I have a section of my site in a subdirectory. My slicknav code works fine for any file in the main directory, hiding the regular navigation on small screens and displaying the hamburger menu icon instead. I assume I need to modify it to work correctly for a page in the subdirectory. I don't see how to do it.

designsondemand.com/about.htm works fine with this standard code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu').slicknav();
});
</script>
```

But designsondemand.com/products/mugs.htm does not execute the code. I have set the link rel to reference the absolute file location, thinking that might be the problem.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.designsondemand.com/slicknavstyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.designsondemand.com/slicknav.css">
```

I would like to know if I can modify my JavaScript slicknav code to execute properly on a subdirectory, or if the only solution is to change my site's structure to do away with subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Fresh night of sleep, new idea on Google search to answer my question. Today it was a search on "jquery on subdirectory." Answers seemed semi-relevant, and in the first one I got the answer although it took two tries. But SUCCESS!

The answer is to modify the script

```
<script src="jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
```

to instead include a leading slash to tell the page to find the code up one directory.

```
<script src="/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
```